# I have installed pandas_datareader in pip but when I try to import the same in Jupyter Notebook it says Module not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

`(py1) C:\Users\XXXXX>pip list
        Version
        ----------------- ----------
        certifi           2018.11.29
        chardet           3.0.4
        idna              2.8
        lxml              4.3.0
        numpy             1.16.0
        pandas            0.23.4
        pandas-datareader 0.7.0
        pip               18.1
        python-dateutil   2.7.5
        pytz              2018.9
        requests          2.21.0
        scipy             1.2.0
        setuptools        40.6.3
        six               1.12.0
        urllib3           1.24.1
        wheel             0.32.3
        wrapt             1.11.1`

and it also works when I type python on my cmd:

`        (py1) C:\Users\XXXXX>python
        Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
        (Intel)] on win32
        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pandas_datareader
> > >       `

However, when I try importing it in Jupyter Notebook (launching from the same venv) it gives me the error below:
`(py1) C:\Users\XXXXX>python`

`        Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC         v.1916 32 bit
        (Intel)] on win32
        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pandas_datareader
> > >       `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve this, I went to my venv and executed this command: **python -m pip install ipykernel** and then **upgraded pip** and it started working.

Thank you,
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning!

so what you could try in the jupyter interface is using a magic command, so just create a new cell with the following content:

```
%%bash
pip install pandas-datareader
```

or

```
%%bash
pip3 install pandas-datareader
```

and run it afterwards. This could be maybe one solution :) did you check the connection of your python3 kernel to the correct environment?

Comment: Thanks Moritz for suggesting on this! But when I execute this command on Jupyter Notebook it says "Requirement already satisfied" and on the next cell when I execute "import pandas_datareader" it results into the same error:

Comment: ah okay! if i come up with a a new solution, i will post it here mohit! i think its just an issue with your environment settings...

Comment: Hi Moritz, I was able to resolve this, I went to my venv and executed this command: python -m pip install ipykernel and upgraded pip and it started working.